# A set S is said to be infinite if there is a one-to-one correspondence between S and a proper subset of $S$ . How is this statement true?

Tags: functions

I was reading about functions and there was a statement given in the book that "A set S is said to be infinite if there is a one-to-one correspondence
between S and a proper subset of S. "

However, I did not quite get it. A one-to-one correspondence between to sets means there exists a bijective function between those two sets.  A bijective function is essentially an one-one(injective) function . Now, a proper subset of a set has a cardinality less than the original set . Thus, there must be atleast two elements in the domain of the function whose values are equal in the function. Otherwise, the range set has to be bigger than the domain (i.e cardinality of the range (or co-domain) set must be greater than the domain set), but that is not true as it is a proper subset of $S$. So, the function is not injective and hence not a bijective function.  Thus, no such one-one correspondence exists between the two sets in either way whether $S$ is finite or not as the co-domain is a proper subset of $S$. So, how is this statement true? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is generally agreed to be infinite, and it bijects with $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: "*Now, a proper subset of a set has a cardinality less than the original set*": **less or equal**, and specifically the definition you've been given is that a set is said to be *infinite* if and only if it has some proper subset that has its same cardinality.

Comment: @PatrickStevens How does $\mathbb{N}$ is bijective with $\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ ? Is it because both $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ , both are infinite . Also, can we say that cardinality of $\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ is less than cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio  Doesn't a proper subset of a set means that the subset has a strictly lesser cardinality than the original set ?

Comment: The definition of a proper subset is any subset other than the original set, i.e. one missing at least one element.

Comment: @J.G. yeah!  That's what I was talking about ...The cardinality of a proper subset (of a set) is strictly less than the cardinality of the set....

Comment: **No it's not.** The definition is excluding at least not one element, not excluding so many elements the cardinality shrinks. Consider the example from @PatrickStevens: biject from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ with $n\mapsto n+1$. I feel like your confusion is you think the bijection needs to be the identity function.

Comment: @J.G.  I didn't get what u meant by " The definition is excluding at least not one element, not excluding so many elements the cardinality shrinks. "....

Comment: The definition of $X$ being a proper subset of $S$ is that $X$ is a subset of $S$, but at least one $x\in S$ satisfies $x\notin X$. The definition has nothing to do with the cardinality of $X$.

Comment: Cardinality need not shrink when you remove elements. Cardinality is an *extremely* blunt way to measure the size of a set; don't try and extrapolate its behaviour from your knowledge of how finite sets work, because finite sets are *abnormally nice*.

Comment: Please note that J.G. has given you an explicit bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\setminus \{1\}$ (where $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ - some define it to include $0$). That is $f(n) = n + 1$. if $f(m) = f(n)$ then $m + 1 = n + 1$ and so $m = n$. I.e., $f$ is injective. And for every natural $n > 1$ we have $f(n - 1) = n$, so $f$ is surjective. So as you can see, it is indeed possible for a set to be bijective with a proper subset. Sets that have this property are given the name "infinite".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot!...I do get it now...Thank you so much!....